# How to add image into axios data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to add an image into Axios data and send the data to .Net Controller. I have never done this before with an image and I need help.
The image source it's not coming from input, but from img tag.

Any idea how to insert the image into a JSON object(data)?
Thank you in advance!

```js
 function PostOffer(){
            let localhost = "https://localhost:7009";
            let url = localhost + "/Client/New";
            let formClientName = document.getElementById("offer-client-name").value;
            let formClientEmail = document.getElementById("offer-client-email").value;
            let formClientPhone = document.getElementById("offer-client-phone").value;
            let formClientDate = document.getElementById("offer-client-date").value;
            let formClientTotal = document.getElementById("main-calculator-total-amount-final").innerText;

            if(parseFloat(formClientTotal) > 0){
                if(formClientName.trim() != "" && formClientEmail.trim() != "" && formClientPhone.trim() != "" && formClientDate.trim() != ""){
                let data = {
                clientName : formClientName,
                clientEmail : formClientEmail,
                clientOfferDate : formClientDate,
                clientPhone : formClientPhone,
                clientTotal : formClientTotal,
                };
                axios.post(url, data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                ClearOfferSend();
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("validation-inputs-send-offer").style.display = "flex";
                }
            }else{
                 document.getElementById("validation-inputs-send-offer").style.display = "flex";
                 document.getElementById("validation-inputs-send-offer").innerText = "Total amount can not be 0";                 
            }
            
        }
```

```html
            <div class="final-form">
                <input type="text" asp-for="Name" id="offer-client-name" placeholder="name" required/>
                <input type="email" asp-for="Email" id="offer-client-email" placeholder="email" required/>
                <input type="text" asp-for="Phone" id="offer-client-phone" placeholder="phone" required/>
                <label for="DateOffer">When do you want to start the project?</label>
                <input type="date" asp-for="DateOffer" id="offer-client-date" placeholder="date" required/>
                <div class="row">
                        <button class="btn-close-final-offer" onclick="CloseOfferForm();">Close</button>
                        <button class="btn-send-final-offer" onclick="PostOffer();">Send</button>
                </div>
                <span id="validation-inputs-send-offer">Inputs can not be empty!</span>
            </div>
```

.NET controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult New([FromBody] ClientAxiosModel offersend)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _clientService.Create(offersend.clientName, offersend.clientEmail, offersend.clientPhone, offersend.clientOfferDate, offersend.clientTotal);
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use input [type="file"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) you can insert image into axios with the following code:

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="image">

// JS code
let formDataImage = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];

// Add in data object too
data.image = formDataImage;
```